# specific divs id's showing hidden divs with matching id

Tags: jquery, click, hidden

I am trying have a "trigger" with a specific `class` show a hidden div that shares the same `class` selected out of a group. For example when you click this:

```
<a class="trigger products">
    Products
</a>
```

it will show the content inside of:

```
<div class="trigger-children products">
    content
</div>
```

There will be multiple classes as `.products` is just one. I have the logic down but just not sure how to write it in jQuery, and write in the most efficient way.  I know it's going to be a `click()` that shows hidden content. So `.trigger-children` will have `display:hidden` in css and be shown on the click.

Please keep in mind that I already have a click event set-up with this system. `.trigger` currently fires it's own `click()` which is doing something different, so not sure if I should combine them. Specifically it is doing:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".trigger").click(function () {
        $(".hidden-content").slideToggle(200);
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/RalphLeMouf/ng86b7z3/

Comment: Not a good idea to assign the same ID to multiple elements,

Comment: @bkVnet see edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect requirement for using `data-*` attributes to specify the elements to target as it keeps the code DRY by requiring only a single click handler. Try this:

```js
$(".trigger").click(function() {
  var targetClass = $(this).data('target');
  $(".trigger-children." + targetClass).slideToggle(200);
});
```

```css
.trigger-children {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="trigger" data-target="products">Products</a>
<a class="trigger" data-target="foo">Foo</a>

<div class="trigger-children products">
  Products content
</div>

<div class="trigger-children foo">
  Foo content
</div>
```

Comment: this works beautifully and I accepted it as the answer, but I'm noticing it is randomly revealing some of the other "trigger-children" on click. Can't really see the pattern as why, doesn't most of the time tho. In other words, more than one trigger-children shows up when only 1 is supposed to.

Comment: AKA they items move out of their designated areas randomly. Its so close tho! Any idea what maybe causing that bug?

Comment: Sounds very strange. Can you setup an example of whats happening in http://jsfiddle.net. I can't replicate it given the code you've shown so far

Comment: it gets a little trickier b/c I'm combining it with another script so maybe there is a better way to combine the two. See edits for the fiddle and many thanks.

Comment: It's reversing the content on the fiddle as well. Do you think it's because I'm using ".trigger" for two different scripts?

Comment: I went ahead and excepted the answer b/c I combined my two function using .trigger and the problem seems to have vanished for now. <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".trigger").click(function () {
     $(".hidden-content").slideToggle(200);
     var targetClass = $(this).data('target');
       $(".trigger-children." + targetClass).slideToggle(200);
    });
   });
   </script>